# Mysql: Adding Two Columns Together Automatically

Tags: mysql

I have three columns in a mysql database:  Column 1, Column 2, and Column 3.

I want to add columns 1 and 2 together automatically to display the sum in Column 3.

I'd like this to be done automatically, so that when a website user enters values in Column 1 and Column 2, they will automatically see the sum in Column 3.

Thanks.

Neil

Comment: +1 to @rid. It's better (by many reasons) to have this value calculated when displayed.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a trigger.You should create a trigger which will be execute when inserting data.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/triggers.html

Answer (score 0):

Depending on a whole host of other things, you probably want one of two options, with a base table having Column1 and Column2 and one of

- a view with a calculated Column3, or
- use a select query when populating your table with

  - select Column1, Column2, Column1+Column2 as Column2

Answer (score 0):

```
mysql_query("update table set column3=column2+cloumn1");
```

Check This:
[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f4b5d/2)